# Adding React-Redux to a React app with React.StrictMode tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

The latest create-react-app has `<React.StrictMode>` tags wrapped around the  component by default. Every example I see that adds react-redux to an application does not have React.StrictMode tags in it.

Here is what I have done:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('root')
```

However, I am always seeing:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('root')
```

I read up on what [StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) is used for. I think it helps with debugging and giving insight on problems within the app so I want to keep it when developing. Is what I did correct or should Provider completely replace it like in all of the examples?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`React.StrictMode` should wrap the whole application including the provider too. So Change your code like bellow:

**From**

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

**To**

```
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

Comment: Got it, how come so many index.js examples out there never show React.StrictMode in them? Is it something added in a later version of React or is it unpopular? Seems useful to me even though I get duplicate console logs on occasion.

Comment: React.StrictMode was introduced in 16.3 version. Also in production mood, this should be removed. And in development mood, many devs dont like it as it render the components twice . Hope the solution was working fine for you.

Comment: Excellent thank you for the explanation. One other small question somewhat unrelated if you don't mind answering. I have been building my react apps without redux so I have a bunch of service.js files that use axios to make all of my API calls. Now with redux I have created actions. Is it proper to keep my services and call them inside of the actions or just completely replace my services with the action files. I am assuming this is preference, but any insight would be great.

Comment: If you are using Redux and you need to call API, then you can use a `middleware` like `Redux-thunk` which is more handy and efficient and also will give you the ability to control the asynchronous API call .